# Have Tag Top Users page show winner of Taxonomist badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, information-display, top-users, taxonomist-badge

I've searched the Taxonomist page to see who won the badge for certain tags, and was unable to find the winners.  How about on the Tag Top Users page you show the winner of the Taxonomist badge for that tag, or the creator of it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, a downvote for me against this proposal purely as I don't see what value adding the winner of the badge would add to the Top Users page, or indeed any other page in the /tags area. It seems more of a "vanity" for the recipient of the taxonomist badge than something that's actually of use.

*Update*: You can determine what tag(s) you've received the taxonomist badge for by clicking the taxonomist badge at the bottom of your profile.

Comment: Vanity, or shame for some of us.

Comment: There are a lot of things on SO that could be considered vanity, like badges themselves.  I mostly want to know, so that I know if it was a badge I created, since there is no way of telling otherwise.  Having been on SO since the beginning, it's hard to keep track of stuff like that, especially since some of it is non-deterministic.

Comment: You could always look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=13295 which is the page you get to if you go to your profile and then click on the taxonomist badge at the bottom of the page... =)